# Sorting an adapter in android, but the view wont update

Tags: android, list, sorting, adapter

So I am trying to sort a list in an android app by clicking a list topic.
The code I have tried is below. This code will sort the adapter, but it won't update the view. I have tried searching, but all the answers says that you just have to call notifyDataSetChanged(), but it does not work here. What's wrong?

```
projectAdapter.sort(new Comparator<ProjectItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(ProjectItem lhs, ProjectItem rhs) {
                        return lhs.getPriority() - rhs.getPriority();
                    }
                });
                projectArrayList = projectAdapter.projectItems;
                projectAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(getActivity(), projectArrayList);
                setListAdapter(projectAdapter);
                getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
                projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: you did not call your sort function . and also you should define sort function after new .

Comment: Could you elaborate? If I check System.out.print(projectArrayList.get(0).getId()) I can see that the list has been sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the code bellow:

```
            projectArrayList = projectAdapter.projectItems;
            projectAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(getActivity(), projectArrayList);
            setListAdapter(projectAdapter);
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
            projectAdapter.sort(new Comparator<ProjectItem>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(ProjectItem lhs, ProjectItem rhs) {
                    return lhs.getPriority() - rhs.getPriority();
                }
            });
            projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @Balle you said that your adapter list has been sorted but not updated in user interface? am i right?

Comment: @Balle i doubt that your 'setListAdapter' function attach adapter to your list correctly.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix that? And yes, the adapter list is sorted, it just does not update the in user interface

Comment: @Balle staff that come in my mind about this is just 2 thing. first is my previous comment about 'setListAdapter' function and second is that in your question you have said that you want to sort your list after clicking on list title. so i expected that you do your 'projectAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' in an event like 'onClickListener' or something like this.